# Access to multiple websites from different domains

Tags: linux, windows, apache, vagrant, lamp

Let's say I've two directories in my Linux Vargant box system:

> /var/www/public/web1/
>
> /var/www/public/web2/

In this Vargant Linux box is obviously installed LAMP and the www directory is root directory of Apache server.

Now I want to access to each website through different domains like these:

> www.web1.dev
>
> www.web2.dev

But not from the Linux Vargant box but from the Vargant host system - Windows 7.

How can I do it?

Comment: I think you need to edit the windows hosts file. Adding IP and domain ex. 192.168.0.22    dev1.dev dev2.dev

Comment: Yes, I've already had created a private network in Vargant config file. But if I do it like you write, it doesn't map the addresses to theirs proper directories, it maps only to the /var/www/public/ directory everytime.

Comment: Leave the vagrant configs as they were, http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-modify-my-hosts-file

Comment: No, it really doesn't work. It would work if I could write something like this to the hosts file: "192.168.0.22/web1/ dev1.dev" but I can't..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, to have windows access either domain, you need to setup a web server(nginx/apache) on the VM and define the local paths to local domains (Virtual hosts) as Toby shown in his answer.    You will then set the IP vagrant assigns the VM to the domains wanted in the windows hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your or the internets DNS server to point web1.dev to the IP address of the client where your website resides, then using apache.

Apache allows you to do this very easily.  You simply need to configure a number of virtual  hosts

```
<VirtualHost www.web1.dev:80>
DocumentRoot "D:/Development/Websites/web1/"
ServerName www.web1.dev


</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost www.web2.dev:80>
DocumentRoot "D:/Development/Websites/web2/"
ServerName www.web1.dev


</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Actually I know about VirtualHost. Your code solve my problem easily but only if I'd access to the websites from vargant box system where is runned apache. But I want to access to the websites from my host Windows 7 system.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what you want to do, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.